# Connection closed using SQL Azure

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, persistence, database-connection

I have a Java server which continuously runs jobs using Quartz as a scheduler.
The goal of this program is to periodically execute calculations, so every T minutes a job starts: it fetches data to verify, does some calculations and saves it back on the database.

The server is run from a VM in Microsoft Azure with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, while the database is SQL Azure.
The ORM I'm using is Ebean 3.3.1-RC2.

I keep getting the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.transaction.JdbcTransaction.rollback(JdbcTransaction.java:642)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.transaction.JdbcTransaction.rollback(JdbcTransaction.java:623)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.BeanRequest.rollbackTransIfRequired(BeanRequest.java:87)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.findId(DefaultServer.java:1241)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.findUnique(DefaultServer.java:1253)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.querydefn.DefaultOrmQuery.findUnique(DefaultOrmQuery.java:908)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.util.DefaultExpressionList.findUnique(DefaultExpressionList.java:189)
at com.db.DAO.findById(ItemDAO.java:89)
at com.jobs.Task.doTask(ItemTask.java:50)
at com.jobs.Job.execute(ItemJob.java:34)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:388)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.rollback(SQLServerConnection.java:1954)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.sql.PooledConnection.rollback(PooledConnection.java:794)
at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.transaction.JdbcTransaction.rollback(JdbcTransaction.java:635)
... 11 more
```

This is my ebean.conf:

```
datasource.azuresql.username=username
datasource.azuresql.password=password
datasource.azuresql.databaseUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://server_name.database.windows.net:1433;database=database_name;user=user_name@server_name;password=password;encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
datasource.azuresql.databaseDriver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
datasource.azuresql.minConnections=1
datasource.azuresql.maxConnections=400
datasource.azuresql.isolationlevel=read_committed
datasource.azuresql.capturestacktrace=true
datasource.azuresql.maxInactiveTimeSecs=30
```

I don't know what to do, I tried changing timeout values, min/max connection number but this exception keeps popping up.
The one thing I noticed is that the system goes well for a bit of time, then I get about 30-40 exceptions like this one and then it all continues as nothing is wrong.

Please suggest a fix, thank you.

Comment: *connection closed* is something you should be handling regardless of whether this is a problem with your code or SQL Azure (e.g. a router dies, the connection will get closed).

Comment: I think it's something a connection pool has to handle. Ebean should be handling it, but something is failing somewhere..

Comment: Connection pooling would reuse unused connection objects so it doesn't have to go to the expense to re-create another connection object--it really doesn't have anything to do with connection objects that are unable to connect to the server.

Comment: I don't know if you have ever used Ebean, but it makes connection handling transparent, so I technically have to write only Ebean.find(Entity.class).findList() to make it create a connection, create a pool of connections and assign one of those connections the burden to execute my instruction. I really don't have control on what's happening under the hood, is it connection pool reuse or connection closed check.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't sound all that useful.  I suspect you'll have to catch the exception and run-through the `Ebean.find(...` process.  Keep in mind, this could happen on any operation performed on the database...  something to wrap Ebean might be the best bet.  I'm not familiar with Ebean--as you might have been able to tell

Answer (score 1):

As stated by one of the comments above, from Peter, the connection pool will help you get a connection already opened. That's it's primary function. The connection pool may also help you by automatically removing connections that are closed; but the connection pool could have a hard time dealing with broken connections. In the .NET world, check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/05/minimizing-connection-pool-errors-in-sql-azure.aspx) that explains that an update to the .NET library was needed to handle this specific condition. If Ebean doesn't implement a similar logic internally that would automatically reopen a broken connection for you, then the burden is on you to implement it.

In addition, adding connection retries against Azure SQL Database is a known and highly recommended pattern. Here is [an older blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/11/10011247.aspx) that shows earlier implementations of this pattern. And here is a more recent [best practice document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn338082.aspx) from Microsoft.